Google Sheets and Google finance behavior on Saturdays?
Why does the formula:
INDEX(GOOGLEFINANCE("USDTRY","price","September 28, 2024"),2,2) 

give #N/A (September 28, 2024 is a Saturday) while the formula:
INDEX(GOOGLEFINANCE("USDTRY","price","September 21, 2024"),2,2) 

returns a value (which is also a Saturday).
How reliable is google finance?

Message is clear GOOGLEFINANCE, the query for the symbol: 'USDTRY' returned no data. So, there is no data on that day.

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093281?hl=en - Data on Google Finance is not reliable as a financial tool. Limited data sources, and if there is any delay that happens on the resource it will be shifted on another day.

Please note that data on Google Finance is unreliable as a financial tool due to its reliance on limited data sources and inconsistencies in information availability. If you read the Disclaimers of Google Finance, it states that:

"All data and information is provided “as is” for informational
purposes only, and is not intended for trading purposes or financial,
investment, tax, legal, accounting or other advice."

One of the inconsistencies of it are the delays or gaps in the data. E.g. There are instances where delay happens on the resource which may lead to missing out the information for the day and that it will only be available the next day.
You can get more information on these public documentations: Disclaimers, Google Finance
